# MVC — как избавиться от дублируемого кода в контроллере?

Tags: php, mvc

Есть функция от javascript - autocomplete.
Чтобы избавиться от дублирования этой функции в разных View, я могу написать ее в отдельном классе в статической php функции (в echo). И потом в нужной View выводить php функцию, которая будет писать мою JS функцию.
Это что касается View. А как быть с контроллером? autocomplete - это AJAX. Есть скрипт на php. Как избавиться от дублирования его в разных контроллерах?
Я не могу отправить данные простому классу (не контроллеру) в url в AJAX. Потому что такого url не существует (класс ведь не контроллер). Я не могу обратиться к другому конроллеру, потому что его экземпляр не создан (у меня открыта View текущего контроллера).

Comment: "Я не могу обратиться к другому конроллеру, потому что его экземпляр не создан" - обратитесь, и он будет создан.

Comment: Вы знаете толк в извращениях: "...в нужной View выводить php функцию, которая будет писать мою JS функцию...". Почему нельзя это сразу в js файле делать?

Answer (score 0):

> я могу написать ее в отдельном классе в статической php функции (в echo). И потом в нужной View выводить php функцию

Это называется в MVC `ViewHelper`

> Как избавиться от дублирования его в разных контроллерах?

Не знаю, какие у вас локальные проблемы - но дублирование бизнес-логики(контроллеры) убирается сведением нескольких контроллеров к одному (при добавлении параметров), либо опять же `ControllerHelper`-ами, или они могут называться `ControllerPlugin` (которые выполняют ту-же роль, что `ViewHelper` , но в контроллере).

И если вы имеете дело с моделями - то часто они могут лучше всех избавить от дублирования, и улучшить одновременно читаемость кода - но эта грань стоит отдельной статьи а то и книги)

Comment: Я разрабатываю на Kohana. Как мне сделать ViewHelper, который будет добавлять Javascript код, не подскажете? Мне бы пример увидеть...
Вообще, получается, я отдельный файл JS подключать буду? А разве это есть хорошо? Ведь чем меньше обращений к серверу, тем быстрее сайт работает. И желательно все скрипты в один файл вообще поместить. Разве нет?

Comment: @Alexandr Nevajno по вашему комментарию видно, что надо курить матчасть - путаница в понятиях, и как это к вопросу относится непонятно. `разве это есть хорошо?` Хорошо, ведь js файл один раз загрузится и положится в кеш, тогда как код страницы будет загружаться каждый раз. Но не всё так абсолютно - когда удобнее сделать встроенный скрипт: делайте встроенный. `Разве нет?` Скрипты в одном файле - это всего лишь небольшой понт. Много подключаемых скриптов - это норма, хотябы потому, что они могут загружаться асинхронно, потому что лишние скрипты можно не подключать.